# Unwanted HTTPs in address

Tags: javascript, https, xampp

I am using **XAMPP** to serve http://tsafterhours.servegame.com.

When attempting to use some of the links in dropdown menus they generate an HTTPS address. **I want to stop this.**

I assume it is being generated from the site somewhere. I have tried using the `.htaccess` file to stop it.

Comment: I have also searched this site prior to posting, thats how I came across fixes via .htaccess files

Comment: `When attempting to use some of the links they generate an HTTPS address` - who wrote the code?

Comment: Look at tooltip.js lines 97, 101 and 106 - you have hardcoded `https://` in there, use **just** `//` - no protocol - so when you DO go to https, you wont need to change that code

Comment: this is a shared site, I just make the changes needed to make it work for my location

Comment: best way to see.... select the category "Recipies" just click the Diamond... it will bring up the list of items.... (...  http://tsafterhours.servegame.com/recipes/ ...)then select any sub-category ...ie Alchemy>Amateur....it freezes for a second and then returns a timeout error and the address changes to (... https://tsafterhours.servegame.com/recipes/alchemy/1 ...) if I remove the HTTPS portion and hit return I get the desired result....

Comment: this is where the files are found... https://github.com/kyau/darkstar-afterhours

Comment: I don't understand why you're going on about it being a shared site, and "best way to see" and "this is where the files are found" ... I told you which file and what line numbers - if that doesn't help you then you'll need to hire someone to do it for you

Comment: Sorry missed the previous comment, changing the lines did not resolve the issue

Comment: Seems to work fine - perhaps you need to clear your cache (or ctrl+f5 while on your site)